# Add App Settings to Terraform automatically using variable group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service

I am using Azure DevOps and Terraform to deploy multiple App Services to Azure, but App Settings of my App Services are changing every time so I had to add them manually to the variable group and to my Terraform configuration which is really annoying and wasting time, so I want when I added them to variable group it will be added to the Terraform configuration automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> Add App Settings to Terraform automatically using variable group:

Yes, you can create a variable group in Azure Devops and access it with the terraform configuration.

You can try below terraform code to achieve the same. I've added the `locals` block to define the values and passed it in `azurerm_appservice`, `app_settings` block to access the variables.

```bash
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.44.1"
    }
  }
}
locals{
app_settings = {
key1 = var.value
key2 = var.value
}
}
provider "azurerm"{
features{}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "example-appserviceplan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "example" {
  name                = "example-app-service"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id

  site_config {
    dotnet_framework_version = "v4.0"
    scm_type                 = "LocalGit"
  }

  app_settings = local.app_settings
}
```

***Terraform successfully initialized after applying the above configuration:***

[image]

Alternatively, you can push settings to an app configuration with pipelines as detailed in [MsDoc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-app-configuration/push-kv-devops-pipeline.md#push-settings-to-app-configuration-with-azure-pipelines).

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I already do the same, the problem is when I have severals keys for exemple 20 keys and are always must be add/delete them, so i had to touch to the terraform configuration each time

Comment: In the same pipeline on which you have configured terraform configuration, add a variable group task using PowerShell to retrieve the app settings.

Comment: @JSecurity exactly. I am facing a similar scenario here to dynamic for loop to set env vars same as azure container apps.

Comment: Whats the issue? @JSecurity